# How to prevent video with playsinline, but without autoplay from autoplaying?

Tags: javascript, video, shopify, html5-video, autoplay

I'm building a section for a Shopify theme.
I've added this to render a video in a popup:

```
<video loop class="video-popup__video" playsinline>
   <source src="{{ video_url }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

As you can see I haven't added the `autoplay` attribute, so I don't expect it to be autoplayed. Everything is ok if you visit the page normally using the URL bar or by switching pages, or if you just refresh the page.

However, when I use the country switcher, (which results in page being refreshed), the video starts playing automatically, which is frustrating. I've found out that if I remove the `playsinline` attribute, this issue doesn't happen. But I need that attribute to prevent video from going full screen when played.

What can be the possible reason ?
I'm sorry that the problem isn't replicable using CodePen, since it's related to Shopify.